# Debugger displays an exception "Unhandled user exception" from within catch statement

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I have the function `getRefreshToken` throwing an `AppException`(defined by me) exception and this function is called from within a catch statement  of a `RefreshToken` method.
When the exception is thrown debugger displays a message `Unhandled user exception` - why?

```
private (RefreshToken, Account) getRefreshToken(string token)
        {

            var account = _context.Accounts.Include(x => x.RefreshTokens).SingleOrDefault(u => u.RefreshTokens.Any(t => t.Token == token));
            //var account = _context.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(u => u.RefreshTokens.Any(t => t.Token == token));
            if (account == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown");
                throw new AppException("Invalid account for token"+ token);
            }
            var refreshToken = account.RefreshTokens.Single(x => x.Token == token);
            if (!refreshToken.IsActive)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown");
                throw new AppException("Invalid token:"+ token);
            }
            return (refreshToken, account);
        }
```

The caller function with catch statement:

```
public AuthenticateResponse RefreshToken(string token, string ipAddress)
{
    log.Info("RefreshToken before locking");
    Monitor.Enter(lockObject);

    using (IDbContextTransaction transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            var (refreshToken, account) = getRefreshToken(token);

        }
        catch 
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "Error occurred.");
            log.Error(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "Error occurred in RefreshToken:");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
            log.Info("RefreshToken after locking");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Why* what? Why it is throwed? Or why it is Unhandled? Or why it is User?)

Comment: Why debugger displays that it is unhandled - it is clearly within catch statement - so it is handled

Comment: You handle `AppException` thrown by `getRefreshToken` with `catch`-block in `RefreshToken` method, and **also** then re-throw it again, so it becomes unhandled as there is no further `catch`-blocks near or over `RefreshToken` to handle retrown exception)

Comment: That was it. Thank you